# How do I make rigid bodies use a curve guide force?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, force-fields, rigidbody

It seems some force types do not effect rigid bodies, does anyone know which forces can actually be used on rigid bodies? In this case I'm trying to get 'debris' to get 'sucked up' by, and carried along the Curve Guide Force. What am I missing? Is there another approach I can take for the same effect?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Curve guide cannot be used with rigid bodies.

As the popup window shows it is affecting only particles.

[image]

you could use a follow path constraint to get your effect.